# Flutter detect user scroll with ScrollController

Tags: flutter

#### Project

Hi, I was trying to build a simple list in flutter with my custom constroller and a listener.
Here is the code

```
class Test2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Test2State createState() => _Test2State();
}

class _Test2State extends State<Test2> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollController.addListener((){
      print('controller called');
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          controller: scrollController,
      itemCount: 8,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            height: 50,
          ),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

#### Problem

My code works as intented but i'm trying to detect user swipes even when there is nothing to swipe. So far, if the list overflows the screen when user swipe scroll listener is called but, when the list of items is shorter than the screen size, this does not happend. 
How can i force listener to always listen?

Comment: tried to use `NotificationListener` instead?

Comment: Does that detect swipe even when list is too short to be scrolled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this code can help you.

**Wrapping the scaffold on a NotificationListener** can listen all event,even itemCount is zero

Dont forget provide an **AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics** physics object

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

    return NotificationListener(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          controller: scrollController,
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 0,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: 50,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      onNotification: (notificationInfo) {
        if (notificationInfo is ScrollStartNotification) {
          print("scroll");
          print("detail:"+notificationInfo.dragDetails.toString());
          /// your code
        }
        return true;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work right now due to this open issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44732

Comment: If I put a function like scroll to index here, I get multiple errors. Is there a way to identify if user is scrolling right then jump to the next right index and if the user is scrolling left then go the the previous index?

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass your custom scroll listener to the function as:

`scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);`

Complete:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
}
```

and your custom scroll listener method:

```
_scrollListener() {
    if (_controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        message = "reach the bottom";
      });
    }
    if (_controller.offset <= _controller.position.minScrollExtent &&
        !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        message = "reach the top";
      });
    }
  }
```

source: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac

Comment: Problem is that scrollListener will not trigger if there isn't an actual scroll. My list in dynamically built and i don't know if the list will overflow screen height

Comment: what do you want to do if the list view isn't scrollable?

Comment: I want to trigger a set state which will collapse the section

Comment: Then why don't you use ``Wrap( children: <Widget>[]) )`` method or column instead?

``Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: <Widget>[],
);``

Comment: Because I don’t know how many list view element will be build. They are dynanic. In the example I hardcoded the number of elements for simplicity

Comment: that's why I  have suggested something for you :) check above your reply to this